# CDI injection source not available in Jersey sub-resource

Tags: java, jersey, cdi, jersey-2.0, hk2

I'm using CDI in a Jersey app. On root resources, CDI injection works as expected, but whenever I return a sub-resource, the CDI injection sources are not available.

My root resource with sub-resource locator:

```
@Path("")
public class MyResource {

    @Inject @Named("name") // works
    private String name;

    @Context
    private ResourceContext context;

    @Path("test2")
    public Object test2() {
        return MySubResource.class;
        //return context.getResource(MySubResource.class); // this does not work either
    }

}
```

The sub-resource:

```
public class MySubResource {

    @Inject @Named("name") // error
    private String name;

    @GET
    public Response test() {
        return Response.ok("Name in sub resource: " + name).build();
    }

}
```

Error:

```
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=String,parent=MySubResource,qualifiers={@javax.inject.Named(value=name)},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1235803160)
```

I'm using `org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi:jersey-cdi1x` and Weld dependencies, running on Undertow, with the Weld servlet listener added to the deployment.

Again, the same injection on the root resource *does* work. The `@Named("name") String` is produced by an `@ApplicationScoped` producer.

**Is this not supposed to work? What am I missing?**

Minimal example Maven project available here:
https://gitlab.com/Victor8321/jersey-sub-resource-cdi

**Note:** An open issue for this exists, but not sure what the official stance on this is: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-3184

Comment: I didn't try your CDI project, but if it doesn't work, then it might be a problem with CDI, because it [works with HK2](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/3d3e76b2c9685b0e680eadee6213bb93). I never really use CDI with Jersey, so I am not sure if CDI still goes through HK2, because the error is thrown from HK2. If CDI doesn't go through HK2, then I guess the sub-resource doesn't go through CDI (since the error is an HK2 error), and that's the problem.

Comment: Which CDI are you using?  GlassFish, WebLogic, something else?

Comment: Did you try injecting your sub-resource? Returning a class won't work there.

Comment: I am pretty sure it works; seen some questions around asking on subresources as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504072

Comment: That question uses `return context.getResource(SubResource.class);` not `return SubResource.class;`

Comment: Returning a sub-resource class or through `context.getResource()` should both work, and they do... It's just that CDI injection doesn't work on the instantiated resource then.

Comment: I'm using the Jersey-Weld integration feature (`org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi:jersey-cdi1x`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/3456, adding a dummy `@Path("xyz")` to the sub-resource class is a "fix". However, that exposes your sub-resource under the dummy path.

Injecting an instance just through CDI works as well (`@Inject Instance<MySubResource> ..`), but then Jersey-managed resources aren't available for injection, such as `@Context HttpServletRequest`.

**I've found 2 other approaches that fully work** (both CDI injection and JAX-RS injection) and have no side effects (as with `@Path`):

- Annotate the sub resource class with `@Provider`.
- `register()` the sub resource class in the `ResourceConfig` (or `Application`).

Both approaches seem to work because they make Jersey - and in turn, CDI - aware of the class.

**Note**: I've updated my example project accordingly for future reference.